# EF Core 5 with an explicit mapping table and explicit relations with fluent API leads to additional foreign keys in the mapping table in the migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Using EF Core 5 with an explicit mapping table and explicit relations with fluent API leads to additional foreign keys in the mapping table in the migration.

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version="5.0.7" and

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version="5.0.7"

Models

```csharp
    public class ModelA
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string SomeData { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<MappingModel> Models { get; set; } = new List<MappingModel>();
    }

    public class ModelB
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string AnotherData { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<MappingModel> Models { get; set; } = new List<MappingModel>();
    }

    public class MappingModel
    {
        public string ModelAId { get; set; }

        public ModelA ModelA { get; set; }

        public int ModelBId { get; set; }

        public ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
    }
```

Application DbContext

```csharp
    public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MappingModel>()
                .HasKey(k => new { k.ModelAId, k.ModelBId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<MappingModel>()
                .HasIndex(uc => uc.ModelAId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MappingModel>()
                .HasIndex(uc => uc.ModelBId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MappingModel>()
                .HasOne<ModelA>()
                .WithMany(u => u.Models)
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.ModelAId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<MappingModel>()
                .HasOne<ModelB>()
                .WithMany(c => c.Models)
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.ModelBId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .IsRequired();
        }
```

The generated migration for the mapping table will be

```csharp
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "MappingModel",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ModelAId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ModelBId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ModelAId1 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: true),
                    ModelBId1 = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_MappingModel", x => new { x.ModelAId, x.ModelBId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_MappingModel_ModelA_ModelAId",
                        column: x => x.ModelAId,
                        principalTable: "ModelA",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_MappingModel_ModelA_ModelAId1",
                        column: x => x.ModelAId1,
                        principalTable: "ModelA",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_MappingModel_ModelB_ModelBId",
                        column: x => x.ModelBId,
                        principalTable: "ModelB",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_MappingModel_ModelB_ModelBId1",
                        column: x => x.ModelBId1,
                        principalTable: "ModelB",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });
```

There are 2 additional foreign keys: ModelAId1 and ModelBId1. This behavior is unexpected. And how I can use fluent API for explicit mapping of mapping table relations?

If you comment the explicit relations (last 2 parts) made with fluent API you get the expected result.

Comment: This is typical mistake with fluent relationship configuration. Make sure to map correctly the navigation properties, otherwise they will be mapped by convention as separate relationships (and FKs). In this concrete case, both `HasOne` calls must specify the corresponding reference navigation property, e.g. `.HasOne<ModelA>()` -> `.HasOne(e => e.ModelA)`, similar for the other.

Comment: Strange, I never get this type of behavior with 3.1. And still, both foreign keys do not always get indexes. Thanx for the explanation.

Comment: Actually one of the indexes is redundant, since it is covered by the PK index. EF Core creates automatically the needed indexes for FK columns (and removes redundant ones) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498619/many-to-many-index-creation-convention/67498924#67498924